# Google Embed API display a list of addreses

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I want to use the Google Embed API.
I have a list of addresses I want to display using the Google Embed API.

Is this possible?
Is there a way for me to pass the entire list to the Google Embed APi so they are all displayed on the map?

Comment: According to the documentation, you can specify only one address in place mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No with the Google Embed API. You can only place one marker on the map. If you want to place multiple markers for your adresses then you will have to do so using the [Maps Java script API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map).